# WebLogic 10 WLST command to stop a deployment

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, wlst

Is there a WLST command to stop a Weblogig deployment? (i.e. the opposite of the nmStart() command)

If so, what is it?

I am changing database passwords and I want to shutdown all deployments so all connections will close. Currently I have to log into the console to shut everything down and I am looking for a quicker way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say [nmKill](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1066305) but I'm not sure about the terminology you are using. The [nmStart](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1106005) is used to start a server in the current domain using Node Manager, not to start a *"deployment"*.

By the way, the WLS Console provides a recording feature that writes out the edits you make in the console to a WLST script. This can be very handy if you are not a WLST expert. To turn on recording, click 'Record' (in the the toolbar near the top of the page). Then, make your edits in the console. Finally, turn the recording off when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

The more usual method, which is independant of whether you're using node manager or not, would be the [shutdown](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21043_01/web.1111/e13813/reference.htm#i1060147) command which is also able to work at the cluster level.